# How to call generic method with a given Type object?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, types

I want to call my generic method with a given type object.

```
void Foo(Type t)
{
     MyGenericMethod<t>();
}
```

obviously doesn't work.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Just because it's hard to find: Using `dynamic` saves you from all the error-prone reflection work. The best answer is there in the referenced question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22441650/143684

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your code sample won't work, because the generic method expects a type identifier, not a an instance of the Type class. You'll have to use reflection to do it:

```
public class Example {

    public void CallingTest()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof (Example).GetMethod("Test");
        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (string));
        genericMethod.Invoke(this, null);

    }

    public void Test<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof (T).Name);
    }
}
```

Do keep in mind that this is very brittle, I'd rather suggest finding another pattern to call your method.

Another hacky solution (maybe someone can make it a bit cleaner) would be to use some expression magic:

```
public class Example {

    public void CallingTest()
    {
        MethodInfo method = GetMethod<Example>(x => x.Test<object>());
        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (string));
        genericMethod.Invoke(this, null);

    }

    public static MethodInfo GetMethod<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expr)
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression) expr.Body)
            .Method
            .GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    }

    public void Test<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof (T).Name);
    }
}
```

Note passing the 'object' type identifier as a generic type argument in the lambda. Couldn't figure out so quickly how to get around that. Either way, this is compile-time safe I think. It just feels wrong somehow :/

Comment: My bad, I changed around some names (tested in a default C# console app, so the class is called Program ;)) Fixed it for you, it should be the name of the class you want to call the method on.

Comment: Great idea with the Expressions. I also can not think of a way to refer to a generic method without specifying at least a generic dummy argument..

Comment: Thank you for providing the "hacky" expressions (ala the best way of doing this IMO) as a starting point.

Answer (score 19):

You need to use reflection, unfortunately (for the reasons Jared mentioned). For example:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("MyGenericMethod");
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);
method.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
```

Obviously you'd want more error checking in reality :)

---

Side note: my local MSDN doesn't specify that the parameter from MakeGenericMethod is a parameter array, so I'd have expected to require:

```
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { t });
```

but it seems it *is* a parameter array in reality, and the [online MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) agree. Odd.

Comment: argghh! The Skeet got me beat :/

Comment: Thanks for reply, Jon. But I have already given the right method, why do I need to load them by name? Isn't there are more safe way which doesn't involve method names as strings?

Comment: Cody: I added another alternative in my answer (trying to beat the Skeet) which doesn't involve strings. It's not as clean as I want, but the idea is clear I think.

Comment: I wonder why there isn't a refactoring-safe way to pass method names around in C# programs. Can we blame Mr. Hejlsberg for that? :)

Comment: You're after the infamous infoof operator. It's on the list of desirable features, but it just hasn't got high enough yet...

Comment: This is not the first time where I would have needed such an operator. Where can I vote for it?

Comment: Umm that was me sorry.  I mis-clicked and hit the wrong arrow.  It won't let me change now.  sorry

Comment: @RobertLevy: Try now - I've edited the answer, so you should be able to change your vote. Not that it really matters.

Answer (score -2):

This approach will not work.  The reason why is that Type is an object who's type is determined at runtime.  However you are trying to use it to call a generic method.  A generic method call's type is established at compile time.  Hence a Type object can't ever be used for a type parameter on a generic method.

Comment: Then what's the solution ? I am also into this topic so much. Thanks.