# Autofixture: How to create instance of type without using generic method

Tags: autofixture

Autofixture has the ability to create an instance of any type using the `Fixture.Create<T>()` method.

But I need to create a type at runtime. By default the non-generic `Fixture.Create()` expects a 'seed', which is not what I want.

How do I create an instance of a given type at runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoFixture: how to CreateAnonymous from a System.Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546850/autofixture-how-to-createanonymous-from-a-system-type)

Answer (score 13):

By looking through the Autofixture source code I worked out I can do it like so:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
Type type = ... // My runtime type
var instance = fixture.Create(type, new SpecimenContext(fixture));
```

Not sure if it's the best way, but it seems to work.