# Method to handle objects with properties in common, but different object types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a large collection of automatically generated objects. Although they are all of different, non-related classes, all of the objects share some basic properties (name, id, etc.). **I do not control the generation of these objects, so unfortunately I cannot take the ideal approach of implementing an interface.** I would like to create a method in which I pass an arbitrary one of these objects and do something using these common properties.

The general idea would be something like:

```
someObj a = new someObj();
a.name = "sara";
diffObj b = new diffObj();
b.name = "joe";
string phrase = string.Format("I am with {0} and {1}", 
    getName(a), getName(b));

private string getName(object anyObjWithName)
{
    return anyObjWithName.name;
}
```

though naturally this does not work.

I thought a generic method might hold the answer, but the only way I can see to call it with the current type is using `genericMethod.Invoke` , which still carries the same issue of not being able to resolve the properties of the passed object in the method. This is unlike [Calling generic method with a type argument known only at execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325156/calling-generic-method-with-a-type-argument-known-only-at-execution-time) or [How to call generic method with a given Type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408120/how-to-call-generic-method-with-a-given-type-object) where only the type, or properties of the type, are used in the method, as opposed to properties of the object.

I am aware that this would be (very) prone to error, but I can guarantee that all objects encountered will have the common properties being manipulated.

Comment: Try either declaring an interface to relate the objects for common properties, or use reflection.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx.aspx

Comment: Ah, perhaps I need to be more clear. I am unable to use good OOP practice and implement an interface because of the way my objects are generated. I do not control this process, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I can guarantee that all objects encountered will have the common properties being manipulated

If that's the case, you can use `dynamic`:

```
private string getName(dynamic anyObjWithName)
{
    return anyObjWithName.name;
}
```

Be aware that using any object that does not have a `name` property will not fail until run-time.

If you want to add a little bit of safety you can catch the `RuntimeBinderException` that gets thrown if the property does not exist:

```
private string getName(dynamic anyObjWithName)
{
    try {
        return anyObjWithName.name;
    }
    catch(RuntimeBinderException) {
        return "{unknown}";
    }
}
```

Comment: For my $.02, I don't think that the OP is in a position to begin the `dynamic` path. The road is fraught with danger and this answer is not pedagogical at all.

Comment: I knew i was in for some pain going into it. As I cannot implement an interface, I'm not sure there is another option.

Comment: Please edit your question with this constraint in big bold letters or many others might go with the dynamic solution when an interface is available to them.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty This is only from .net 4.0 and up as far as I know.

Comment: @KeithPayne Updated! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @ispiro Good to know, but looks like I lucked out on this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're unhappy with the performance using dynamic as mentioned by D Stanley, you could always try [FastMember](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/).

All you need to know to start using it is pretty much shown in the first 2 code examples.

Comment: Wow, yeah, this library literally exists to solve this exact problem. I wonder how it does it under the hood without reflection...

Comment: @MaxPRafferty: IIRC, it will leverage reflection to get the member information the first time, write equivalent compile-time IL, then used that compiled code for subsequent access to that type/member. This gives it speed closer to compiled code when compared against frequently hitting the DLR or reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Rube Goldberg device there. You should just have all your data objects classes implement a single interface, then you can work on that. Much simpler and less error prone than fiddling with reflection.

The very fact that a lot of objects have common properties but don't share the same ancestry, on in the very least a common interface, shows that something is wrong with your design. Do rethink it.

Comment: That's really where the problem comes in - I don't control the generation of the objects. My kingdom for an interface!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to accomplish this, simplest probably is to create Interface and declare common methods there, have your object implement it, then change "getName" method take interface object

```
private string getName(IMyInterface anyObjWithName)
{
    return anyObjWithName.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is with an interface, if you own the types that you're working with

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TypeOne : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set }

    public string BespokePropertyOne { get; set;}
}

public class TypeTwo : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public float BespokePropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<IEntity> entities = new List<IEntity>();
    entities.Add(new TypeOne() { ID = 1, Name = "Bob", BespokePropertyOne = "blablabla" });
    entities.Add(new TypeTwo() { ID = 2, Name = "Alice", BespokePropertyTwo = 5.4f });

    foreach (IEntity entity in entities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} Name: {1}", entity.ID, entity.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP doesnt have a way to control classes. Its mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was written before the edit to the question stating that interfaces weren't possible in this case. Perhaps it can help someone else reading this question.

Interface:

```
interface Iname
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Use interface:

```
class A : Iname
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class B : Iname
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The method:

```
string GetName(Iname o)
{
    return o.Name;
}
```

Use:

```
A a = new A { Name = "First" };
B b = new B { Name = "Last" };
Text = GetName(a) + " " + GetName(b);
```

Comment: OP doesnt have a way to control classes. Its mentioned in question.