# Getting underlying object C# by passing in a string at runtime

Tags: c#, generics

So I have a method that Creates a new object like so:

```
public class Objects<TObject>
{
    public NodeReference<TObject> CreateObject<TObject>(TObject objectType) 
                where TObject: class, new()
            {
                NodeReference<TObject> nodeReference = 0;

                return nodeReference;
            }
}
```

Now I have other object classes that define other object type like, Car.

```
public class Car
{
    public int NumberOfDoors {get; set;}
    public int NumberOfWheels {get; set;}
}
```

Now lets say I get passed a string how would I convert this string into its type at runtime?

`var carObjectReference = CreateObject<//string converted to identify object car dynamically>(//new Car { });`

Comment: You will need to use an `Activator` class. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7598427/706456)

Comment: If you can convert your string to a `Type`, then you can continue with the techniques shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408120/how-to-call-generic-method-with-a-given-type-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public object ReturnValue(string operationName, object returnValue)
{
    Type t = returnValue.GetType();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
}
```