# UnRegister viewmodels MVVLight at logout

Tags: xamarin, mvvm-light

When I register the views models I do

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register(
    () => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstanceWithoutCaching<INewsViewModel>(),
    flow.Guid.ToString());

ViewModelsCache.Instance.AddViewModelInfo(flow.Guid.ToString(), INewsViewModel);
```

After I logout I am trying to do:

```
foreach (var viewModelInfo in ViewModelsCache.Instance.ViewModelsInfo)
{
    Type type = viewModelInfo.Value.GetType();             
    SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<type>(viewModelInfo.key);
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> 'type' is a variable but is used like a type

Do you have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: I'm wondering why do you want to unregister ViewModels? Otherwise, you can find the answer for your question -> 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408120/how-to-call-generic-method-with-a-given-type-object

Answer (score 0):

What about to unregister all the instances?

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Reset();
```